# Compose a function that returns a function, which uses a function inside it, with Lodash

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, lodash, function-composition

Just me slowly getting familiar with FP, using plain Lodash, to start with.

I'm trying to create a `isCode` function, that will return `true` on the following:

```
const code = 'EAI_AGAIN'
const error = {code: 'EAI_AGAIN'}

isCode(code)(error)
```

Currently this works:

```
const getCode = partial(get, _, 'code')

const isCode = function(string) {
    return function(object) {
        return equal(string, getCode(object))
    }
}
```

and this:

```
const isCode = string => flow(getCode, partial(equal, string))
```

but I wonder how it would look like "one level deeper" / "point-free(?)".

I've tried various ways, unsuccessfully:

```
const isCode = curry(equal, _, partial(getCode))

const isCode = curry(partial(equal, _), partial(getCode, _))

const isCode = partial(curry, equal, partial(getCode))
```

Which are mostly shots in the dark, as I couldn't figure out what the correct terms to search for would be, and none of the "FP introductions" I found went as deep as this - seemingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `_.isEqual()` expects two values, and will not invoke functions, so when you curry it, it will compare the function to the string, and won't try to extract the value from the object.

The `_.flow()` statement is pointfree enough, and more it's readable:

```
const isCode = string => flow(getCode, partial(equal, string))
```

Another option is to partially apply `matchesProperty`:

```js
const { matchesProperty, partial } = _

const code = 'EAI_AGAIN'
const error = {code: 'EAI_AGAIN'}

const isCode = partial(matchesProperty, 'code')

const result = isCode(code)(error)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You should also try [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide), because in the fp version, all methods are curried, have a fixed arity, and are in the right order:

```js
const { matchesProperty } = _

const code = 'EAI_AGAIN'
const error = {code: 'EAI_AGAIN'}

const isCode = matchesProperty('code')

const result = isCode(code)(error)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Indeed, seems like it. Thanks for the `matchesProperty` tip as well!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you would want to do this, but the code could look something like:

```js
function isCode(code){
  return function(error){
    if(code === error.code){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
const code = 'EAI_AGAIN';
const error = {code: 'EAI_AGAIN'};
console.log(isCode(code)(error));
```

Comment: Both for practical and learning reasons. The code for a `isCode` function could look like yours, which is quite similar to my imperative example, but neither of them features function composition (for example: https://gist.github.com/joelnet/3f419efa39d7a1505cd18036061ae516), which is what I'm looking for :)